# How to resolve error: no such partition after removing Ubuntu on a triple boot system?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

My system consists of Ubuntu, Elementary OS, and Windows 10.
After removing the Ubuntu partition in Windows, I restarted the system and got the error: `Error: no such partition. Entering rescue mode...`

I followed through with the solution on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/495993/618228), and I got the options to enter the Elementary or Windows OSes. However, selecting either of the options did not work and instead I was again redirected to the previous  `Error: no such partition error` screen. Now I can only login to Windows from BIOS, but I am not able to login to Elementary OS in any way.

How can I remove this error?

Comment: Don't know, but there are a couple of utilities to try: grub rescue and grub-customizer. You can run them from a live CD or flash drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting  https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer https://www.supergrubdisk.org